# HTML5 Boilerplate + Conditional Comments

Tags: html, boilerplate, conditional-comments, selectivizr

I am using the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) and never had a problem with it until now, when I have started using [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). For some reason, which I dont understand, IE8 produced a Javascript error.

After some testing, I noticed that the error was gone when I stopped using the conditional browser comments (in the Boilerplate) that add a class to `html` depending on the browser you are using:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

As I said, when I remove the code above and replace it with `<html>` everything works fine.

Since I dont want to remove the conditional comments completely (they help me to write browser specific css), I thought of doing the same, but instead of applying it to `html` I will do it for the `<body>`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <body class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <body class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <body class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <body class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Everything seems to work okay, but since I am a newbie, I would just like to verify that this workaround is okay? Or is there a downside?

And one more question offtopic: When a user visits the site with Firefox or Chrome, what `body` will be "used"? I guess it will "use" `body` without a class?

My logic would tell me to write another conditional comment, to make sure to "use" `body` for all other browsers, however in the official Boilerplate template no such comment exists and therefor I guess its not needed... Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We actually originally had them on the `<body`> tag. :)

We moved them for two small reasons:

- The multiple classnames bug in IE6
- CMS's that use the body element for their own classes.

You can move the classes to `<body>` without much problem. You can also leave `lang=en` on the HTML element, cleaning things up.

More deets here: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/44

Comment: Also if you could file a ticket with selectivizr about your IE8 issue, you should. :)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it! I will use the `body` tag for now + I will file a ticket with selectivizr and in case they can solve the problem, I will undo the changes.